# Problem with nmea_navsat_driver

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to connect MBED C027 with gps to ROS Kinect. I install package and I want to to try run ROS as in example from http://wiki.ros.org/nmea_navsat_driver

**$ rosrun nmea_navsat_driver nmea_serial_driver _port:=/dev/ttyUSB0**

but on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS there is no dev/ttyUSB0 but dev/ttyACM0 so I change above formula to :

**$ rosrun nmea_navsat_driver nmea_serial_driver _port:=/dev/ttyACM0**

and I have message on my terminal:

```
[WARN] [1488637721.102995]: Received a sentence with an invalid checksum. Sentence was: 'JJB\x011$@\x040`\xc4\x8c\xa5JJJJ\xd6\x95c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\[..][WARN] [1488637721.121065]: Received a sentence with an invalid checksum. Sentence was: '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00$GPRMC,142841.00,V,,,,,,,040317,,,N*76'
```

[WARN] [1488637721.122125]: Received a sentence with an invalid checksum. Sentence was: '$\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00$GPRMC,142841.00,V,,,,,,,040317,,,N*76' [WARN] [1488637721.123186]: Received a sentence with an invalid checksum. Sentence was: '$\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00$GPRMC,142841.00,V,,,,,,,040317,,,N*76'

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/nmea_navsat_driver/nmea_serial_driver",
> line 52, in 
> data = GPS.readline().strip()   File
> "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py",
> line 511, in read
> raise SerialException('read failed: %s' % (e,))
> serial.serialutil.SerialException:
> read failed: (4, 'Interrupted system
> call')

I consider that this path dev/ttyACM0 might cause problem to connect but I can't find a solution
Anyone have any advice?

Thanks :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256125/problem-with-nmea_navsat_driver/) by [Aleksandra](https://answers.ros.org/users/29559/aleksandra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-03-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There might be two reasons for that.

1. Ensure that You pass the right baud as a parameter.

More important however is to ensure on the receiver side that is it casting NMEA messages.

---

Originally posted by [Marek](https://answers.ros.org/users/24929/marek/) with karma: 18 on 2017-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0